# "you can't vote to delete/undelete this post"

Tags: support, review, voting, deletion, 10k-tools

In the "review > Tools" page (available only to users with at least 10000 reputation points), in the list of posts to delete/undelete, some titles are displayed in a light color and I cannot cast votes upon them. What criteria do I have to meet in order to be able to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have not used up your daily delete-vote allowance, it may not be a criteria that you as a user have to meet, but a criteria that the post has to meet. Here are some restrictions for applying delete votes.

1. Users with between 10,000 and 19,999 reputation can only vote to delete **closed/on-hold questions** which have been closed/on-hold for at least two days.
2. Users with ≥20,000 reputation can vote to delete **closed/on-hold questions** of score ≤-3 at any time, but still have to wait to vote to delete higher scored closed/on-hold questions.
3. Users with ≥20,000 reputation can vote to delete **negatively scored answers**.

<s>Being reopened does not remove delete votes on a question, but and does prevent regular users from casting further delete votes.</s> An answer of score -1 being up-voted does not remove pending delete votes on an answer, but does prevent regular users from casting further delete votes.

I guess technically speaking a criteria that you as a user could meet to remove these restrictions is to be either elected as a site moderator, or hired by SE as a CM. Diamond encrusted users have no limitations on casting delete votes.

Comment: Each post that I see in the "Tools > Delete votes" is displayed in the format *number title (number)*. What do *number* and *(number)* signify? Right now, I see, for instance, *"2 How big is infinity? (1)"* that I can vote for, and *"2 How to solve 4 variables (1)"* that I can't.

Comment: @AlexM. The format for these is [number of pending votes] [post title] ([number of further votes needed for action]). It is the same across close/reopen votes and delete/undelete votes. Tool tips should pop up when you hover over these numbers.

Comment: I see, so in the case of *"2 How to solve 4 variables (1)"* (this particular one shows up in the "Most Votes" category), given that there have already been cast 2 votes, why can't I vote too? How have those votes been cast? And if I can't cast votes on this, why is it shown in the "Tools > delete" page after all? Shouldn't such posts simply be filtered out and not get displayed anymore, given that I cannot act upon them? Understanding the questions in this comment would answer my original question.

Comment: @AlexM You cannot vote to delete because that answer has scored 0 (it is not _negatively_ scored). It appears in the 10K Tools Delete tab because it accumulated delete votes in a [low quality review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/704361) and carried a down vote through a low quality flag, removed when the flag/review ended with an edit.

Comment: Those pages list posts with pending votes, and those pending votes remain pending even if regular users cannot cast further such votes.

Comment: I think that your last comment is the answer that I was looking for. I also believe that the functionality of the "Tools" page should be altered: why would I want to be presented with posts that I cannot act upon? "Tools" are things that you use in your *actions*, so posts that cannot be acted upon should have no place there. But I believe that this has nothing to do with MSE anymore, but rather with the SE software on a global level, so the implementation of this behaviour is not something that I should ask here for.

Comment: @AlexM. While there may be posts listed in the 10K tools  that you cannot immediately vote to delete, there will usually be preparatory steps that you can take. But requesting a change in the functionality of these pages would probably be best presented on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think that reopening does cancel standing deletion votes. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23384/do-deletion-votes-dissolve-when-a-question-is-reopened-when-else

Comment: @Asaf  Gaaaccckk!!! All the Byzantine rules! I must have gotten confused with the fact that reopen votes don't expire when a question is deleted.

Comment: Tow points on the tools page: first, as alluded to by @arjafi, sometimes you can do something to be able to deleted (again), namely first downvote the post, then vote to delete. Second, whil I also found it annoying sometimes to be presented (sometimes mainly) with votes on which I cannot cast a delete vote, I question the statement that '"tools" are things that you use in your actions' for the context of this site. The "tools" page is all about *information* not actions. There is nevert action to be taken right there; it just allows you to locate posts where some action might be needed.

Comment: @arjafi Your last sentence your answer: Why are CM.Diamonds encrusted? Hmmm I would have thought that Community Moderators are entrusted with the SE net-work.